# how to use slash command in discord bot without reinviting?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to use slash command without reinviting bot in the server.
discord.js 12.5.1
node v12

I tried to reinvite with permission **applications.commands** and it works.
but I want it without reinviting anyone can help?.

Comment: Impossible. You don't have to kick the bot before re inviting it if that's what you mean, but you can't just *give* the permission just like that

Answer (score 0):

Just use the link again with **applications.commands** selected. **No need for a reinvite.**

There may be other ways of doing it, but here's 1 of them.

You will need to go to your [Discord Applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications) page and add the permissions you need, along with **applications.commands**. From there, you need to just "invite" the bot as you would normally. Copy and use the link provided. The bot's permissions in the server will update accordingly.

If this is a large public bot, just inform the users that Slash Commands can be added by using your invite link once again, without kicking the bot or losing any data.